# How do I create Metalness, Roughness and Specular Maps?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I was experimenting with Blender's new Principled BSDF node. I came to know about various new maps - like Metalness map, roughness map and specular map.

Can anyone here please explain these maps in simple language here?

Previously I used to create Normal maps, bump maps, AO maps mostly in GIMP using Insane Bump plugins. It is very handy and fast.

But how to create these new maps? Do we have any similar plugins that will convert a texture into these new maps?

Comment: I watched Blender Guru video on Principled shader recently and it goes into Metalness and Roughness/Fresnel quite well - https://youtu.be/4H5W6C_Mbck

Comment: @RichSedman well i asked this question after watching that particular video :D actually I wanted to know how to make/geberate those maps? Is there any plugin in gimp or any open source programme that can solve the problem?

Comment: It's a tooling and creative problem. You could look at substance painter.

Comment: @Sidar is there any open source alternative?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But perhaps you can look into some of the workflows and maybe adapt those in blender?

Comment: @Sidar any link to any such tutorials?

Comment: Perhaps these help : https://www.3dtotal.com/tutorial/2170-pbr-textures-and-material-creation-in-blender-misc-by-pierrick-picaut-sketchfab-video-tutorial Not specifically what you asked for but definitely helps build some maps for them